# How to fetch email, subject and name separately using imap_headers() in php?

Tags: php, email

I'm trying to fetch the email address from email account. Following script is working fine for me.

```
$mbox = imap_open("{mail.b******n.com:143/novalidate-cert}", "myEmail@b******n.com", "myPassWord");
$headers = imap_headers($mbox);
print_r($headers);
if ($headers == false) {
    echo "Call failed<br />\n";
} else {
    foreach ($headers as $val) {
        echo $val . "<br />\n";
    }
}
imap_close($mbox);
```

Above code is returning date, email address (`if no name`) and subject.

Example : 
`[1118] =>       1119)13-May-2016 Facebook    You have more friends on  (16765 chars)`

```
[1192] =>       1193)25-May-2016 John  Re: B****c Website Feedba (27152 chars)

[1224] =>       1225)30-May-2016 k****n@b***n.c DSR is not submitted prop (83005 chars)
```

Means above code returning the email if email has no `From: Name`. So is there any way to fetch the email addresses only? I would like to appreciate if someone guide me regarding this. Thank You

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might want to fetch message information with [imap_fetch_overview](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.imap-fetch-overview.php):

```
$MC = imap_check($mbox);

$result = imap_fetch_overview($mbox,"1:{$MC->Nmsgs}",0);
foreach ($result as $overview) {
    echo "#{$overview->msgno} ({$overview->date}) - From: {$overview->from}
    {$overview->subject}\n";
}
imap_close($mbox);
```

Comment: Can you kindly let me know that can i fetch `to` and `cc` as well ? Thank You

Comment: see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18715440/php-imap-retrieve-all-recipients-in-to-address

Comment: Thanks i'm checking

Comment: I check it does not working, can you kindly check [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39745784/how-to-fetch-to-and-cc-email-using-imap-php)